# Calculate EM field of accelerated charge

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity

When calculating EM field of a constant speed moving charge, we can take the EM field of a rest charge (Coulomb's equation) as starting point then apply Lorentz transformation to get the result.

When calculating EM field of an accelerated charge, we seems to take another approach, i.e. start with Maxwell's equation, like in chapter 12.11 and chapter 14 of Jackson's textbook.

Special relativity only applies to inertial frame and I think this is why we can't calculate an accelerated charge's EM based on rest charge's EM. But since general relativity applies to non-inertial frames, can we take rest charge's EM as starting point and apply some similar GR transformation to get the result directly?

Comment: The canonical "accelerated coordinates" are the [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates). Did you try and see whether transforming the EM field from inertial rest to these coordinates agrees with the EM field Jackson calculates?